# Jetpack Compose + Navigation - Nested navigation with BottomNavBar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-bottomnav

I'm trying to implement the following screen flow using Jetpack Compose + Jetpack Navigation:

[Navigation concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yRhU.jpg)

Actually, i am able to code two singles cases:

- SplashScreen --> HomeScreen (with no BottomNavBar)
- HomeScreen (with BottomNavBar) --> Tabs

I'm not able to code the whole problem. In fact, i have an issue with the management of the NavHost. In the first case (SplashScreen -> HomeScreen) i need to call the NavHost at a high scope:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MyAppTheme {
            //init the Navigation Controller for screen navigation
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            //setup the Navigation Graph
            SetupNavGraph(navController)
```

while in the second case i need to call it in the `innerPadding` scope of the `Scaffold` composable:

```
fun MainScreen(navController: NavHostController) {

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavBar(navController)
        }
    ) { //innerPadding scope
        //setup the Navigation Graph
        SetupNavGraph(navController)
    }
}
```

Please assume that `SetupNavGraph()` function works as intended (call `NavHost` to generate the navigation tree)

- I tried to use two `NavHost` without success.
- If i setup the `NavHost` in `setContent()` i'm able to load the splashscreen and move to an empty `BottomNavBar` screen. If i click on the `BottomNavElements` i'm able to navigate to the child tabs (in the example above "Favorite","Music","Places", "News") but the `BottomNavBar` disappears
- I cannot setup `NavHost` in the `innerPadding` scope because this is loaded only after switching to the main screen (in the example above "Favorite Tab" + BottomBarNav)

The only workaround i found is generating the `BottomNavBar` composable in each of the BottomNav child tabs, but this generates a visible transition effect that i would like to avoid and, generally, doesn't seem a good practice.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand the question

Comment: Sorry and thx for editing. I added a more complete explanation and an example image of what i would like to achieve. Even if you can't answer, for the sake of being clear, could you tell me if what i ask is now understandable? Thx!

Comment: Yeah, It's now clear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution. This are the steps to achieve the desired result:

1. Create two different NavGraph, one for Splash->MainScreen and the other for the BottomNavBar

```
const val ROOT_ROUTE = "root"

@Composable
fun SetupRootNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.FirstScreen.route,
        route = ROOT_ROUTE
    ) {
        composable(Screen.FirstScreen.route) { FirstScreen(navController)}
        composable(Screen.SecondScreen.route) { MainScreen(navController)}
    }
}
```

```
const val BOTTOM_BAR_ROUTE = "bottomBar"

@Composable
fun SetupNavGraphBottomBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = BottomBarScreen.FirstElement.route,
        route = BOTTOM_BAR_ROUTE
    ) {
        composable(BottomBarScreen.FirstElement.route) { FirstElementScreen() }
        composable(BottomBarScreen.SecondElement.route) { SecondElementScreen() }
        composable(BottomBarScreen.ThirdElement.route) { ThirdElementScreen() }
    }
}
```

2. Init the `NavController` and the `RootNavGraph` after `setContent()` in your `MainActivity`. This will be in charge of the SplashScreen -> MainScreen navigation tree.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {

                //init the Navigation Controller for screen navigation
                val navController = rememberNavController()

                //setup the Root Navigation Graph
                SetupRootNavGraph(navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Re-init the `NavController` in the Screen where you have your BottomNavBar ("MainScreen" in the example) and the assign to it the `BottomNavGraph` in the `innerPadding` scope.

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavHostController) {

    //Re-initialize the NavController to set a new NavGraph
    val navControllerBottomBar = rememberNavController()

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavBar(navControllerBottomBar)
        }
    ) {
        //setup the Navigation Graph
        SetupNavGraphBottomBar(navControllerBottomBar, user)
    }
}
```

And this will work like charm! Of course you will need to structure your `BottomNavBar` in order to manage the navigation as documented on [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav)

Comment: Question: Your MainScreen is part of which Graph? ROOT_ROUTE  or BOTTOM_BAR_ROUTE ?

Comment: You found me at the end. :) It's root route. Btw, I suggest you to read another similar post. This solution is not the best if you have that a tab of the bottomnav need to navigate to a screen without bottomnav.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71395630/jetpack-compose-navigate-both-with-and-without-bottombar/71425065#71425065 this is the post I suggest you to read

Comment: But you lose the ability to navigate between the two graphs right?  How do you go from the BottomNavGraph back to the MainNavGraph.  EG if the main graph was a login flow, when your session expires one would want to navigate from the bottom graph back to the main graph

Comment: You are absolutely right. Unfortunately I was not able to find a solution with nested navigation. I prefer the solution in the other post (the other one you commented) because is more consistent and organized, even if it's still more a workaround than a solution